# No notifications about comments on answers to my question

Tags: support, comment, notifications, comment-replies

I've asked a question and it was answered (I got notification about it). Then several comments were added to that answer and I got nothing. Shouldn't I get notifications about everything concerning my question?

I'm not sure whether it worked or not anytime, so I don't know if that a bug or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only get notifications for comments on posts that you own or when you participated in the comments and someone addresses you with `@Yrogirg`. You *don't* get notifications for comments on answers to your own question, the answers are not owned by you.

Comment: Somehow I've thought otherwise. But Mad Scientist is absolutely correct: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work